# tf.maximum not returning expected result (rookie)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an time series forecast that I generated via an RNN model.  The time series is a zero-bounded, positive series, and the forecast generated a negative value.  I thought I could just replace the value with a zero by using the following code:

```
y_pred = sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={X: X_test})  # generate the forecast values
y_pred0 = tf.maximum(y_pred, tf.zeros(tf.shape(y_pred)))  # eliminate values<0
```

The tensor dimensions match...

```
print(y_pred.shape)
print(y_pred0.shape)
print(y_pred0)

(1, 11, 1)
(1, 11, 1)
Tensor("Maximum_2:0", shape=(1, 11, 1), dtype=float32)
```

... but the y_pred0 tensor seems to have no values assigned... what did I miss?  I tried intializing y_pred0 with tf.zeros(shape(y_pred)), but that yields the same results.  I am sure this is a rookie mistake, but I have spent too much time trying to resolve it at this point.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up symbolic and numeric computations here. Tensorflow ops more or less always return symbolic tensors -- they only contain information that can be inferred from how they are computed (such as shape or dtype) but no actual values. Values are computed via a `run` call within a session, and these values are usually returned as numpy arrays.

In your example, you have a numpy array in `y_pred` (the output of `run`), but feed this into `tf.maximum`. This will now create the *symbolic* `maximum` op, which returns a symbolic tensor as well. The numpy array you put in is actually converted to a tensor under the hood. You have two options here:

1. Simply use `np.maximum` on `y_pred`.
2. Since you likely want to use Tensorflow: Define an op like `outputs0 = tf.maximum(outputs, tf.zeros(tf.shape(outputs)))` and then evaluate it via `sess.run(outputs0, feed_dict={X: X_test})`. This is assuming that `outputs` represents some symbolic computation as in your example.

Comment: Many thanks... as predicted, rookie mistake.  Appreciate the thorough response!

Answer (score 0):

The code does what it should for me:

```
import tensorflow as tf

if __name__ == '__main__':

  y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor([1,0,-1,1,-1])
  y_pred0 = tf.maximum(y_pred, tf.zeros(tf.shape(y_pred), dtype=y_pred.dtype))

  with tf.Session() as sess:
      print(sess.run(y_pred0))
```

yields:

```
[1 0 0 1 0]
```

Maybe you have problems with your feed dict or session? In case you're wondering why the print output is Tensor("Maximum_2:0", shape=(1, 11, 1), dtype=float32), Tensorflow is building a graph before execution. That means at this time no real values are available, only shapes and flow. If you want to print the values, you have to do it from an execution session like I did in my example.

Comment: Also, many thanks -- two answers and both educational -- for me at least.